# What term is more correct — "achronologisch" or "antichronologisch"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, adjective, grammaticality, prefix

Which of the two following German translations for *reverse chronological* (as in: *reverse chronological order*)

> achronologisch

and

> antichronologisch

is the correct form, or are both correct? Do they mean the same? Or is there a subtle distinction between *anti-* and *a-*?

Comment: I would actually say *nicht chronologisch* or *in umgekehrter chronologischer Reihenfolge*.

Comment: Another way would be to say `chronologisch ungeordnet`or `in verkehrter zeitlicher Reihenfolge`. Though I would not use `in verkehrter chronologischer Reihenfolge`.

Comment: @Deve und Tim: Sieht "...isch" wie eine englsiche Endung aus?

Comment: @userunknown Zu dem Zeitpunkt als wir unsere Kommentare gepostet haben, lautete die Frage noch anders, sh. Editierverlauf.

Comment: @Deve: Okay, habe sie als obsolet markiert. Kannst Deinen aber auch selbst löschen.

Answer (score 10):

They are both correct, but have different meanings.

The `a-word` construction indicates a lack of `word`, whereas the `anti-word` construction indicates something against `word`.

In your example, something which is "achronological" is something without a time-based order.  For example, I could say my notebook is achronological, as I write on random pages on random days.

Something is "antichronological" (this is a odd word however) if it is in reverse chronological order.  For example, if I wrote on my notebook from the last page to the first page, I could say it is antichronological.

Comment: Anti can mean "opposite to some direction", so here it could mean "opposite to the direction of time". It could also mean "opposite to some meaning/perspective/attitude". So one could also use this adjective for anything, that disturbs the chronological order.

Answer (score 8):

I don't think those words really exist in German. At least I couldn’t find them on duden.de.

The only context I found them (both) via Google was with CVs. So I guess it’s an anglicism that came to Germany with the American style CVs recently.

OregonGhost posted the correct translations in his comment. However, *antichronologisch* sounds wronger to my ears than *achronologisch*.

Comment: Yes, as I noted even in English "antichronological" is very weird.  It is much more normal to see "reverse chronological" instead, which is a synonym.

Comment: These are technical terms that are not listed in a dictionary like the Duden which aims at everyday users. Since many technical terms are created within an international society of scientists and technologists, and since many of these kinds of terms are created ad hoc and forgotten again, it would take extensive research to find out where they originated.

Comment: I agree with @Toscho that putting "anti" in front of chronologisch is ambiguous. It could either mean "in reverse (chronological) order" or it could mean "not chronological" (the same as achronistisch). Therefore using this word composition just seems *plain wrong* to me. One should rather explain the intention more clearly, for example "in umgekehrt chronologischer Reihenfolge".

Answer (score 4):

The prefixes "a-" and "anti-" have different meanings. "achronological" means "not proceeding through time in an ordered fashion", while "antichronological" means "proceeding backwards through time".

Example: Most movies rewinded are antichronological, while e.g. [Memento](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0209144/) is achronological,

Answer (score 1):

The best translation for *reverse chronological* is, remarkably, the literal translation:

> Umgekehrt chronologisch

[A Google search](https://www.google.de/#q=%22umgekehrt+chronologisch%22) confirms that this is used in German.

Answer (score 1):

Antichronologisch and Unchronologisch don't really exist in German.

It's more common to say

> Nicht chronologisch

eng. non-chronological

> Anachronistisch

eng. anachronistic

[Duden.de](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/anachronistisch)

Answer (score 0):

I see some people have problems with their own language. *Unchronologisch* would be proper to us; the prefix *un-* is used to show the opposite of something, like *unlogisch*, *unglaublich* etc.

Comment: There's a difference between "unchronolgisch" (not chronological, i.e., in random order) and "antichronologisch" (in reverse order).